# GroovyString hashCode and equals do not evaluate to same value as String

Tags: string, dictionary, groovy

Recently, I was working in our codebase on a bug where I found that looking up a value in a HashMap by String produced the correct result whereas looking up a value by GStringImpl using "${key}" produced an incorrect (null) result.  The following is a test I did in the Groovy console:

```
def myMap = ["testString" : "value"]
def testString = "testString"
println myMap.get("${testString}")
println myMap[testString]
println "${testString}".getClass()
println testString.getClass()

String myString = "test"
def myGroovyString = "${myString}"

println myString.equals(myGroovyString)
println myString.hashCode()
println myGroovyString.hashCode()
println myString.compareTo(myGroovyString)
```

the output produced was the following:

```
null
value
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
class java.lang.String
false
3556498
3556535
0
```

Now, if I change the definition of the map to be an implementation of TreeMap such as the following:

```
def myMap = ["testString" : "value"] as TreeMap
```

I get the following result:

```
value
value
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
class java.lang.String
false
3556498
3556535
0
```

I understand that the reason why this happens is probably because (I did not look at the implementation of HashMap vs. TreeMap) HashMap looks up a key by hashCode() whereas TreeMap is going to use compareTo(...).  My question is why do String and GStringImpl not produce the same hashCode() and not produce a true result when equals(...) is used?  Is this a bug/design error?  Or was this done for a reason?  It seems the results of these methods should be compatible since interactions between these classes are supposed to be seamless to the programmer. The result of this is a huge potential for mistakes in code that might seem intuitive at first but results in a bug in map lookups.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` (the default `Map` type in Groovy) performs a lookup based on the `hashCode` of the object.

`TreeMap` performs a `compareTo` call on the root of the tree, and goes off down the left or right branch depending on the result of this (and returns the value if `key.compareTo( node.key )` returns `0`)

As you have seen

```
println myString.compareTo(myGroovyString)
```

prints `0`.  This is why the item is found in the `TreeMap`, and the different `hashCode` is why it is not found in the `LinkedHashMap`

Groovy Strings are not Strings, they are a templating mechanism and a completely different object.  This is why you get different results for `hashCode` -- see the [*'GStrings aren't Strings'* section on this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString)

Comment: +1 for the link.  I wish I would have caught this quote from the section you referenced sooner:  "There is no automatic coercion between the two types for comparisons or map keys, so it's sometimes necessary to explicitly invoke toString() on GString objects."  It still seems counter-intuitive to me...but I'm going to accept your answer since this is obviously well-documented in the Groovy documentation and I'm assuming they don't plan to change it.