# Groovy Strings vs Java Strings

Tags: java, groovy

I have a string in groovy that I make from other strings, example:

```
def final PREFIX = "myprefix"
def prefix2 = PREFIX + ".whatever1"
```

Now suppose I have a `HashMap` and I want to do a lookup using `prefix2` as part of a key:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>()
map.put("myprefix.whatever1.value","aaa")
```

If I do:

```
def key = "${prefix2}.value"
String result=(map.get(key))
```

Then `result = null`, but if I do:

```
String key="${prefix2}.value"
String result=(map.get(key))
```

Then `result = aaa`.

I can understand why this happens, obviously a type inference issue. But I still find it makes me feel icky. Something just doesn't "feel right" about it. Do you know what I mean?

Is this type of thing normal and should be "expected"? Am I asking for too much for Groovy to know that if I created the string using quotes, it should work when being used to look up a value in a `Hashmap <String, String>` without being defined as a `String` object reference? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: If a string uses interpolation it's a GString. That's just the way it works; it's neither a bug nor a feature. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7591157/438992

Comment: Take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-885 - basically "won't fix"

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030483/groovystring-hashcode-and-equals-do-not-evaluate-to-same-value-as-string

Comment: This is also helpful http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple things that need to be take into consideration why this is happening.

When you create a variable `HashMap<String,String> map` you would expect that like in java you would only be able to add strings as keys and values to it. This is not the case in groovy as the type arguments will not be taken into consideration which means the following will work:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>()
map.put(1, 2)   
assert map.get(1) == 2
assert map.get(1) instance of Integer
```

Also as you stated, an interpolated string like `"${prefix2}.value"` is an instance of `GString` (`GStringImpl` to be specific) so the following is true

```
def key = "${prefix2}.value"
assert key instanceof GString
```

So, `map.get(key)` will get invoked with a `GString` parameter without an error since the String constraint is dropped, which would not be an issue if the `GStringImpl` would give the same hashcode as the `String`, but it doesn't

```
assert key == "myprefix.whatever1.value"
assert key.hashCode() != "myprefix.whatever1.value".hashCode()
```

This is why the get on the map returns a `null`

The way to work around this is, as you stated using either `toString()` or assigning the GString to a String variable (`toString()` is called implicitly)

Another way, which I would prefer, is to not mix the usual java style map access with the groovy one. If you use the property notation or key indexed on the map using the GString it will work perfectly:

```
def final PREFIX = "myprefix"
def prefix2 = PREFIX + ".whatever1"

// def map = [:] // shorter will be a LinkedHashMap
HashMap<String,String> map = [:] as HashMap // if you really need HashMap
map."myprefix.whatever1.value" = "aaa"

def key = "${prefix2}.value"

assert map[key] == "aaa"
assert map."${prefix2}.value" == "aaa"
assert map."$key" == "aaa"
```

Comment: Oh I see, interesting, groovy compiler processes property notation on map (`map."myprefix.whatever1.value" = ...`) as a gstring? So if you use `map."${prefix2}.value"` instead that will work as well? (you don't need to hardcode `map."myprefix.whatever1.value"` ) I will try it out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You can call toString() method of GString (interpolated string in groovy), which will return a java.lang.String, so if you want to use such a string to retrieve a value from a HashMap, for example, you would use it like so:

```
 def prefix = "some.string"
 map.get("${prefix}.value".toString())
```